# Cayley's Theorem on a Cyclic Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

(**Update: My attempted solution is at the bottom**)

I need to find G', which is the set of permutations that is isomorphic to the given G, and find an isomorphism from the given G to the group G'.

I was able to do two similar questions but this one has me stumped because I don't know how to start.

I am given that G is the cyclic group  of order 5. I can't really show what I've tried because I can't seem to start . One of the other problems that I could solve had G as the additive group $\mathbb Z_3$ (I am including how I solved it so that you can see how I/my textbook went about solving it. I don't know if it is/can be done differently). I started by listing the elements of $\mathbb Z_3$ like this:
$$\mathbb Z_3=\{[0], [1], [2]\}$$ 
and went on further saying: Let $f_a:\mathbb Z_3 \rightarrow \mathbb Z_3$ be defined by $f_a(x)=a+x$ for each $a\in \mathbb Z_3$
$$f_{[0]}:\begin{cases}
f_{[0]}([0])=[0]\\
f_{[0]}([1])=[1]\\
f_{[0]}([2])=[2]\\
\end{cases}
\qquad f_{[1]}:\begin{cases}
f_{[1]}([0])=[1]\\
f_{[1]}([1])=[2]\\
f_{[1]}([2])=[0]\\
\end{cases}
\qquad f_{[2]}:\begin{cases}
f_{[2]}([0])=[2]\\
f_{[2]}([1])=[0]\\
f_{[2]}([2])=[1]\\
\end{cases}$$
Thus $G'=\{f_{[0]},f_{[1]},f_{[2]}\}$ where $f_{[0]}=[0], f_{[1]}=([0],[1],[2]), f_{[2]}=([0],[2],[1])$.

The isomorphism is $\phi:\mathbb Z_3 \rightarrow G'$ where $\phi$ is defined as:
$$\phi:\begin{cases}
\phi ([0])=f_{[0]}\\
\phi ([1])=f_{[1]}\\
\phi ([2])=f_{[2]}\\
\end{cases}
$$

The underlying problem is I don't know how to write out the elements of G where G is a cyclic group  of order 5. (This is what I think it is $G= \langle a\rangle=\{a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5\}$ but I feel that I am totally wrong.)
Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

---

From the comments/hints this is what I was able to come up with. I am not sure if this is what was being suggested, but if anyone could look at my work and tell me if I got it right, I would appreciate it. (Oh and I didn't know if I was supposed to edit the question and add my understood solution, if I wasn't then I'm sorry.)

$G=\langle a \rangle =\{1, a, a^2, a^3, a^4\}$ Let $f_b:\langle a \rangle \rightarrow \langle a \rangle$ be defined as $f_b(x)=bx$ for each $b\in G$.Thus
$$f_1:\begin{cases} 
f_1(1)=1\\ 
f_1(a)=a\\ 
f_1(a^2)=a^2\\
f_1(a^3)=a^3\\ 
f_1(a^4)=a^4\\ 
\end{cases} 
\qquad f_a:\begin{cases}
f_a(1)=a\\
f_a(a)=a^2\\
f_a(a^2)=a^3\\
f_a(a^3)=a^4\\
f_a(a^4)=a^5=1\\
\end{cases}
\quad f_{a^2}:\begin{cases}
f_{a^2}(1)=a^2\\
f_{a^2}(a)=a^3\\
f_{a^2}(a^2)=a^4\\
f_{a^2}(a^3)=a^5=1\\
f_{a^2}(a^4)=a^6=a^5a^1=a\\
\end{cases}$$
$$f_{a^3}:\begin{cases}
f_{a^3}(1)=a^3\\
f_{a^3}(a)=a^4\\
f_{a^3}(a^2)=1\\
f_{a^3}(a^3)=a\\
f_{a^3}(a^4)=a^7=a^5a^2=a^2\\
\end{cases}
f_{a^4}:\begin{cases}
f_{a^4}(1)=a^4\\
f_{a^4}(a)=1\\
f_{a^4}(a^2)=a\\
f_{a^4}(a^3)=a^2\\
f_{a^4}(a^4)=a^8=a^5a^3=a^3\\
\end{cases}$$
Thus $G'=\{f_1,f_a,f_{a^2},f_{a^3},f_{a^4}\}$ where $$f_1=id,\ f_a=(1,a,a^2,a^3,a^4),\ f_{a^2}=(1 a^2,a^4,a,a^3),\ f_{a^3}=(1,a^3,a,a^4,a^2),\qquad f_{a^4}=(1, a^4,a^3,a^2,a)$$.

The isomorphism $\phi:\langle a \rangle \rightarrow G'$ is defined as 
$$\phi:\begin{cases}
\phi (1)=f_1\\
\phi (a)=f_a\\
\phi (a^2)=f_{a^2}\\
\phi (a^3)=f_{a^3}\\
\phi (a^4)=f_{a^4}\\
\end{cases}$$

Is my solution fine?

Again, 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know about cycle notation in the symmetric group?

Comment: I think you can denote $G'$ by $S_G$ or something like that instead because $G'$ stands for another certain subgroup notation.

Comment: Your elements representing the cyclic group of order $5$ are okay, but it's better to write $1$ instead of $a^5$.  (They are the same thing.)  This is analogous to how we typically write remainders mod $5$ as $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, or $4$.

Comment: @SammyBlack to your first comment, when I write $f_{[0]}=[0], f_{[1]}=([0],[1],[2]), f_{[2]}=([0],[2],[1])$ isn't this in cycle notation?

Comment: @user66807 Yes, fine. Except that $f_{[0]}=[0]$ looks odd. Should be $f_{[0]}=(\,)$ or $f_{[0]}=\operatorname{id}$ or something.

Comment: Oh, yes.  Except for the identity permutation, you ought not use the symbol $[0]$, which is one of the objects being permuted.

Comment: IMHO, the notation is a bit clunky, tending to obscure the simplicity of what's going on.  The *point* of isomorphism is to allow you to write things differently and have them mean the same thing!

Comment: @SammyBlack oh I understand, I think I was thinking that the identity is $0$ because in $\mathbb Z_3$ the identity is $0$

Comment: @SammyBlack you said "it's better to write 1 instead of $a^5$. (They are the same thing.)" I had a bit of trouble understanding "order," so can you explain a little on how $a^5$ is the same as 1?

Comment: Saying that an element $a$ has order $5$ means that $a^5 = 1$ (the identity) and that no smaller power yields the identity (*i.e.* $a^k \ne 1$ for all $0 < k < 5$).

Comment: @SammyBlack ah, okay I understand that now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_5 = \langle a \rangle$ be the cyclic group of order $5$, generated by $a$.  Let $S_5$ be the symmetric group permuting the symbols $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$.

A group homomorphism $\varphi: C_5 \to S_5$ is completely determined by where you map $a$.  Note that $\varphi(a)$ must have order $5$ in order for the map to be well-defined.  In other words, $\varphi(a)$ needs to be a $5$ cycle.  Why not $\varphi(a) = (1\;2\;3\;4\;5)$?  Hence, $\operatorname{Im}\varphi = \varphi(C_5) = \langle (1\;2\;3\;4\;5) \rangle$.

(Where do all the other elements map to?)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The cyclic group of order 5, as you already stated, is $G=\{e, a, a^2, a^3, a^4 \}$. Then consider the map $\phi: G  \rightarrow \langle (12345) \rangle$, where $\phi$ sends each $a^i$ to $(12345)^i$ for $i=1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.